# Is this a bug in ruby Regexp? How to guard against "infinite loop" from regex match without using Timeout?

Tags: regex, ruby, ruby-2.7

I have this regex:

```
regex = /(Si.ges[a-zA-Z\W]*avec\W*fonction\W*m.moires)/i
```

And when I use it on some, but not all, texts e.g. this one:

```
text = "xation de 2 sièges-enfants sur la banquette AR),Pack \"Assistance\",Keyless Access avec alarme : Système de verrouillage/déverrouillage et de démarrage sans clé,Park Assist: Système d'assistance au stationnement en créneauet et en bataille,Rear Assist: Caméra de recul avec visualisation de la zone situ"
```

like so: `text.match(regex)`, then ruby just runs in what seems like an infinite loop - but why? And is there anyway to guard against this, e.g. by having ruby throw an exception instead - without using the `Timeout` as it is a known issue when using it with Sidekiq (https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Problems-and-Troubleshooting#add-timeouts-to-everything)

ruby version: 2.7.2

Comment: Looks like an issue with the positive character class, and using the negated version will solve it, `/Si.ges[^\d_]*avec\W*fonction\W*m.moires/i`

Comment: There is no match for `(Si.ges[a-zA-Z\W]*avec\W*fonction\W*m.moires)`

Comment: @Thefourthbird Sure, that is why there is a problem.

Comment: It would be interesting to condense this into an [mcve], with an emphasis on the word "minimal". What is the shortest/simplest string and regex you can find to replicate the issue?

Comment: Is it an infinite loop or is it just a very long loop?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Ah, catastrophic backtracking probably, but I would not expect that. Do you know why that is?

Comment: @Thefourthbird It does not look like catastrophic backtracking (at least in its usual form). The `i` modifier and `\W` in the character class seems to cause the issue.  [Here](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/4044), I believe, we can find something to explain this. Probably, related to "*mutiple Case Unfold definitions in unicode.c*".

Comment: So, the regex is surely not defined as it was intended to work and I can solve that with the colleague of mine who wrote it - but - what really concerns me here is I would not have expected that you could end up in a death spiral like this without getting at least an error, just because you write a poor regex and used it on a particular string. It’s kind of scary I would say...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: interesting link, but all the bugs related in this page seems to be solved in more recent Ruby versions (at least since 2.5 on which I tested them). I think the fourth bird theory may be correct: `a.*b.*c` is clearly a pathological pattern.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte `a.*b.*c` is pathological as `.` matches `a`, `b` and `c`, but `a\W*b\W*c` should not be pathological as `\W` does not match these letters. At any rate, removing `i` flag solves the whole problem.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I read too quicly, I thought it was `a[\Wa-z]*b[\Wa-z]*c`, so something very near from `a.*b.*c` but it isn't the case. After several tests with only `/Si.gesX*avec\W*fonction/i` (with X the character class), the problem occurs when `\W` is with `a-z` (whatever the way you find to hide the fact there is the full `a-z` range), but the problem disappears if you remove a letter from the range. Same problem with `\W\p{L}`. Even with a succeeding pattern, the result is very slow.

Comment: Yeah, I came to the same conclusion - the point is - is this a bug in ruby's regex implementation, because it does not seem to be the same problem with e.g. running the regex match in C++...

Comment: I didn't go through all the comments, but could it have something to do with this section here? [a-zA-Z\W]

\W means [^a-zA-Z0-9_] so you may see how it could generate a conflict.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Built-in character classes are more table-driven.
Given that, Negative built-in ones like `\W`, `\S` etc...
are difficult for engines to merge into a positive character class.

In this case, there are some obvious bugs because as you've said, it doesn't time out on
some target strings.

In fact, `[a-xzA-XZ\W]` works given the sample string. It times out when `Y` is included anywhere
but just for that particular string.

Let's see if we can determine if this is a bug or not.

First, some tests:

***Test - Fail  [a-zA-Z\W]***

https://rextester.com/FHUQG84843

```
# Test - Fail  [a-zA-Z\W]
puts "Hello World!";
regex = /(Si.ges[a-zA-Z\W]*avec\W*fonction\W*m.moires)/ui;
text = "xation de 2 sièges-enfants sur la banquette AR),Pack \"Assistance\",Keyless Access avec alarme : Système de verrouillage/déverrouillage et de démarrage sans clé,Park Assist: Système d'assistance au stationnement en créneauet et en bataille,Rear Assist: Caméra de recul avec visualisation de la zone situ";
res = text.match(regex);
puts "Done";
```

***Test - Pass [a-xzA-XZ\W]***

https://rextester.com/RPV28606

***Test - Pass [a-zA-Z\P{Word}]***

https://rextester.com/DAMW9069

---

Conclusion: Report this as a BUG.
IMO this is a BUG with their built-in class `\W` which is engine defined,
since `\P{Word}` is a Unicode property defined function, not a range.
And we see that `[a-zA-Z\P{Word}]` works just fine.
Use `\P{Word}` inside classes as a temporary workaround.

In reality when modern-day engines were first designed, the logic of what
a negative class was `[^]` each item is AND NOT which when combined with a positive
class where each item is ORed results in errors in scope.
Perl had class errors still a short time ago.